# Faking viewport width to mimic smaller screens on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, viewport

I have a parent container that has Bootstrap `div.row` elements with `div.col-...` children inside. Using jQuery I change the containers width and height to mimic mobile devices so that the user can preview the layout in different sizes.

However, as Bootstrap col classes react to viewport width, setting the containers width to, say, 500px, doesn't trigger the columns to float differently.

How do I overcome this? It should only affect elements inside a specific container in the page.

Comment: Most browser's dev console has it built in...

Comment: No time for a full answer now, but have you considered putting the user content inside a suitably sized iframe?

Comment: use some kind of container, say `<div class="mimic">...</div>`, nested inside any grid cell and assign width to it by js.

Answer (score 0):

You could display it in an `<iframe>`

`<iframe src="http://yourdomain/example.html width="350px">`

be aware Cross-domain issues